# Need help in solving the differentiation

Tags: calculus

I want to differentiate the following expression with respect to n:

$\frac{d}{dn}[1-{(1-p)^n}^d]$

I do not know which formula to use to differentiate this term with respect to n. Please can anybody help me?

I have tried like this:

$\frac {d}{dn}(1-{(1-p)^n}^d)= -\frac{d}{dn}[{(1-p)^n}^d]=-\frac{d}{dn}[e^{n^dln(1-p)}]=-e^{n^dln(1-p)}.ln(1-p).dn^{d-1}$   Is my answer correct?

Comment: Can you differentiate $a^x$ with respect to $x$? And if you write it as $e^{x \ln a}$?

Comment: Yes. $\frac{d}{dx}(a^x)$ is $ lna.a^x$.

Comment: Correct. Now apply that to your expression.

Comment: Ok. I am going to try that now. Thanks.

Comment: $\frac {d}{dn}(1-{(1-p)^n}^d)= -\frac{d}{dn}[{(1-p)^n}^d]=-\frac{d}{dn}[e^{n^dln(1-p)}]=-e^{n^dln(1-p)}.ln(1-p).dn^{d-1}$   Is my answer correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dn}[1-{(1-p)^n}^d]$ $=-\frac{d}{dn}[{(1-p)^n}^d]$

Let $u={(1-p)^n}^{d}$

therefore $lnu=n^dln(1-p)$

hence  $\frac{d}{dn}[lnu]$=$=\frac{d}{dn}[n^dln(1-p)]$

$\frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{dn}$= $n^d\frac{d}{dn}[ln(1-p)]+ln(1-p)\frac{d}{dn}[n^d]$

$\frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{dn}$= $\frac{n^d}{p-1}\frac{dp}{dn}+ln(1-p)n^{d-1}.d$

$ \frac{du}{dn}$=$u(\frac{n^d}{p-1}\frac{dp}{dn}+ln(1-p)n^{d-1}.d)$

$ \frac{du}{dn}$=${(1-p)^n}^{d}(\frac{n^d}{p-1}\frac{dp}{dn}+ln(1-p)n^{d-1}.d)$

therefore required answer

$- \frac{du}{dn}$ $=-\frac{d}{dn}((1-p)^n)^{d}$=${-(1-p)^n}^{d}(\frac{n^d}{p-1}\frac{dp}{dn}+ln(1-p)n^{d-1}.d)$

If you asssume p to be a constant then $\frac{dp}{dn}=0$

Hence

$- \frac{du}{dn}$ $=-\frac{d}{dn}((1-p)^n)^{d}$=${-(1-p)^n}^{d}.ln(1-p)n^{d-1}.d$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: please upvote if it helped you

Comment: May I know how to do that?

Comment: by clicking on the triangle facing upwards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the $d$ in the exponent is a real number and that $p\leq 1$:
$$\frac{d}{dn}[1-(1-p)^{n^d}] = -\frac{d}{dn}(1-p)^{n^d} 
= - \ln(1-p) \times (1-p)^{nd} \times \frac{d}{dn} (n^d) \\ = - n^{d-1}d(1-p)^{nd}\ln(1-p)$$
Which I believe is the same as your answer, although simplified.

Comment: p cannot be equal to 1 it will be strictly less than 1

Comment: I believe x^t ln(x) goes to 0 for x going to 0

Comment: x going to zero is a different thing which doesn't necessarily means that x can be zero

Comment: Thank you so much.